# #1054 - column not available, but it is available in defination

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm updating a column of one table based on a column of another table.
And getting error of "#1054 - Unknown column 'debit_note_detail.id' in 'where clause'".

I tried to find any hidden character in the string but everything I found perfect. Here I'm uploading screenshot of tables.

[image]

[image]

```
update certificate_of_origin
set certificate_of_origin.cert_type = debit_note_detail.type_of_coc
where debit_note_detail.id = certificate_of_origin.dbtnotedt_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` `debit_node_detail` to `certificate_of_origin` to be able to access its columns. Try this:

```
update certificate_of_origin
join debit_note_detail on debit_note_detail.id = certificate_of_origin.dbtnotedt_id
set certificate_of_origin.cert_type = debit_note_detail.type_of_coc
```